# Python OpenCV .imshow() doesn't produce the same colors as .VideoWriter()

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently programming a particle simulation with Python. I am using OpenCV to display a three-dimensional array (height, width and bgr) as an image. This has worked so far, but as soon as I want to convert these frames to an .mp4 file with .VideoWriter(), the colors are no longer displayed correctly.

[.imshow()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZWgZ.png)
[.VideoWriter()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSvmp.png)

Here is the relevant code:

```
image = np.zeros((cons.height, cons.width, 3), np.uint8)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, cons.frame_rate, (cons.height, cons.width))

for i in range(cons.length * cons.frame_rate):

    image[:, :, 0] = cons.b
    image[:, :, 1] = cons.g
    image[:, :, 2] = cons.r

    ref_points = [np.array(cons.particles[i].position) for i in range(len(cons.particles))]
    tree = cKDTree(ref_points)

    for i in range(len(cons.particles)):
        image[int(cons.particles[i].position[1]), int(cons.particles[i].position[0])] = cons.rules[cons.particles[i].id]

    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("Particle Life", image)
    output.write(image)

    for i in range(len(cons.particles)):
        acceleration = np.array([0,0])

        nearest_points_index = tree.query_ball_point(cons.particles[i].position, cons.rmax)

        for j in nearest_points_index:
            r = cons.particles[j].position - cons.particles[i].position
            rlen = np.sqrt(r.dot(r))

            if 0 < rlen and rlen < cons.rmax:
                acceleration = np.array(acceleration) + np.array((r / rlen) * f.force(cons.beta, rlen / cons.rmax, cons.matrix[cons.particles[i].id][cons.particles[j].id]))

        acceleration = acceleration * cons.rmax
        cons.particles[i].update(cons.dt, cons.friction, acceleration)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
                break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
output.release()
```

I have tried various codecs, but none of them have solved the problem. I also tried to change the input format, although .VideoWriter() actually requires BGR, but it doesn't work either. Converting to avi instead of mp4 does not solve the problem either.

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to be the same, given that you're comparing the raw source image with one that has gone through a lossy video compressor (on default settings). Especially with the image in question being basically a single-pixel noise.

Comment: Thank you @DanMašek for your reply! I thought it might be due to the compressor. How could I fix this problem to really get the raw source images as video?

Comment: From what I can gather, H.264 and H.265 (amongst others) support a lossless mode. So you just need to do some research to find out how to configure the encoder to use this mode. Not sure whether OpenCV provides the means to do so. If not, you may have to use ffmpeg or something like that directly. Or save it as uncompressed video (in AVI format? it's going to be huge tho), or sequence of PNGs and convert it afterwards using command-line ffmpeg.

Comment: @DanMašek I already tried H.264 aswell as saving it as an uncompressed video (AVI). Both didn't work. Using the MoviePy library didn't change anything aswell, still the same problem.